# Check class with guard statement swift

Tags: swift

In my class i want to check my model class using guard feature. I try to do following;

```
func bindWithModel(model: Any)-> Void {

        guard let model is VacanciesItem else {

        }
    }
```

However, it throw me an error - Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer

How to fix it?

Comment: Since `model` is passed as a parameter, it should be `guard model is VacanciesItem`.

Comment: not only because it is passed as a parameter ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## remove the let.

`let x = x` would be an assignment. you dont have any assignment though as you only test with `is`.

so `guard model is VanaciesItem`

### OR if you want to cast and assign it in one:

`guard let model as? VanaciesItem`

(I think that what you want most often)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the let keyword:

```
guard model is VacanciesItem else
```